# How to tell when animations finished playing inside directive as to call focus() on input

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

Is there an "Angular way" of knowing when animations are done on an element?
I want to call `focus()` on an input after it's animated in.

Currently, I have to options on the table:

- `setTimeout(fn,0);` which is hacky
- listen for `transitionend` event which will not trigger if the browser doesn't support transitions

I'm hoping that injecting `$animate` in the directive might give me this info though.

How would you do it?